# Odd Scaling Behavior in Android ICS WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application that displays html pages from resource assets in a WebView. The WebView was chosen in order to permit navigation links on the page, and all navigation action is handled in a WebView Client class by interrupting new page requests and returning the required local asset. The activity that contains the WebView supports both portrait and landscape orientations, and the WebView is configured ("setInitialScale" and "WebSettings") in "onCreate". Pages are displayed to fit inside the width and vertically scrollable. This has worked fine until the ICS update.

Under ICS the initial page selected still displays as before, but further page links that are displayed are wider than the screen width (and include a horizontal scroll bar). This occurs if the device is in portrait or landscape orientation when the initial page is loaded. Rotating the device to landscape and back to portrait solves the problem (causing a re-load of the activity as if the displayed page were the first one), but navigating back to previous pages while in portrait orientation causes them to again have widths that exceed the device display, even when returning to the primary page which was displaying correctly.

This is mostly an annoyance - but the inconsistent behavior is worrying. Unfortunately, there are several other "tweaks" associated with this code (mostly to re-size images within the html to fit the screen and retain the WebView scroll position when the orientation changes). While these could be a source of the current problems, a quick log output of their results shows they are working as expected, suggesting it is the ICS WebView behavior has changed.

I have searched for any similar postings of the problem without finding any direct reference, so my question is really open. Has anyone else seen anything like this in the ICS WebView class, or should I be looking for another source for the changed behavior?

**Update:**

After eliminating one line of code after another for hours (grrrr), I have identified the problem.

When running under android api 14 or higher, the WebView has unpredictable behavior after setting the view scale with "setInitialScale" to values larger than 100% when the viewport is fixed at the device width (using the meta tag name="viewport" content="width=device-width" in the html css). The initial page load seems to respect the device width, but subsequent page loads may or may not render with the viewport wider than requested, almost randomly.

This may be the expected behavior, although the unpredictability suggests that it is not (and if it is, then it is a fix from the behavior under previous versions).

The code used was setting the scale to allow the user to adjust the text display size in preferences, with the size of page images being "fixed" to a value in code before the page is loaded. This has been replaced by maintaining the page scale at 100%, and setting the text size from the user's preferences using "WebSettings.setDefaultFontSize", which has removed the rendering problems.